# use javascript variable as url for addthis:url

Tags: javascript, syntax, addthis

I need to pass a url to `addthis`, and this is the default code

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="http://www.google.com" >
```

I need to pass the url to addthis with a javascript variable, I need it something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentUrl = 'http://www.google.com'; 
</script>
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url=currentUrl >
```

Do you know the syntax to add this javascript variable ?

Answer (score 2):

First, add `id` to the `div`:

```
<div id="MyAddThisToolbox" class="addthis_toolbox .....>
```

Then have this code after the `<div>` tag in the body of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("MyAddThisToolbox").setAttribute("addthis:url", currentUrl); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what 'addthis' is but you can try following:

```
<div ... addthis:url="javascript:currentUrl">...</div>.
```

Can you explain what 'addThis:url' is and where have you got it?

Comment: hi,

This is where it is from https://www.addthis.com/help/url-and-title 

And also found how to change the url, it can be done with this script

<script type="text/javascript">
    var shareUrl = "http://www.msn.com/";
    addthis.update('share', 'url', shareUrl);
</script>